# Angular JS use one view for two two URLS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I write following two views together as one - both of them sharing the same `contrl`, same `templateurl`, same `url` with different params?

```js
$stateProvider.state('user-view', {
  params: {
    selectedTab: 0
  },
  templateUrl: './resources/user-view.html',
  url: '/user-view/:userId',
  controller: 'useriewCtrl',
  resolve: {
    user: ['userService', '$stateParams', function (userService,
      $stateParams) {
      return renewalService.getUser($stateParams.userId);
    }],
    selectedTab: ['$stateParams', function ($stateParams) {
      if ($stateParams.selectedTab != null) {
        return $stateParams.selectedTab;
      }
      return 0;
    }]
  }
});

$stateProvider.state('user-view', {
  params: {
    selectedTab: 0
  },
  templateUrl: './resources/user-view.html',
  url: '/user-view/:dataeofbirth/:address',
  controller: 'useriewCtrl',
  resolve: {
    user: ['userService', '$stateParams', function (userService,
      $stateParams) {
      return renewalService.getUser($stateParams.dataeofbirth,
        $stateParams.address);
    }],
    selectedTab: ['$stateParams', function ($stateParams) {
      if ($stateParams.selectedTab != null) {
        return $stateParams.selectedTab;
      }
      return 0;
    }]
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take params as part of query string instead of part of url and you need to do this as ui-router would need keys to know what is userId and what is dob and address.

```
$stateProvider.state('user-view', {
  params: {
    selectedTab: 0
  },
  templateUrl: './resources/user-view.html',
  url: '/user-view?userId&dataeofbirth&address',
  controller: 'useriewCtrl',
  resolve: {
    user: ['userService', '$stateParams', function (userService,
      $stateParams) {
        if($stateParams.userId)
            return renewalService.getUser($stateParams.userId);
        else
            return renewalService.getUser($stateParams.dataeofbirth, $stateParams.address);
    }],
    selectedTab: ['$stateParams', function ($stateParams) {
      if ($stateParams.selectedTab != null) {
        return $stateParams.selectedTab;
      }
      return 0;
    }]
  }
});
```

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZAIWpuFHxclY9hfpfhQC?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

State `url` gives you ability to provide *optional* fields.

So you can merge:

- `'/user-view/:userId'`
- `'/user-view?userId&dataeofbirth&address'`

to something like:

```
url: '/user-view/:userId?/:dataeofbirth?/:address?'
```

However the main disadvantage of this approach, the `$state` doesn't know how to populate 3 optional arguments.

so if we will write:

- `/user-view/userId12` - OK
- `/user-view/dataeofbirth3/address4` - here we will get:

  `userId = dataeofbirth3` and  `dataeofbirth = address4`

<kbd>[Demo that demonstrates the problem in Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/lnbzQdsLRfdPYHmKT9ZY?p=preview)</kbd>

So we can just write:

```
url: '/user-view/:arg1?/:arg2?/:arg3?'
```

or with usage of `squash`:

```
 url: '/user-view/:arg1/:arg2/:arg3',
 params: {
           arg1:       {squash: true, value: null},
           arg2: {squash: true, value: null},
           arg3:      {squash: true, value: null}
         }
```

---

```
$stateProvider.state('user-view', {
  params: {
    selectedTab: 0
  },
  templateUrl: './resources/user-view.html',
  url: '/user-view/:userId?/:dataeofbirth?/:address?'
  controller: 'useriewCtrl',
  resolve: {
    user: ['userService', '$stateParams', function (userService,
      $stateParams) {

      if($stateParams.arg1 && !$stateParams.arg2){// we have only userId
         return renewalService.getUser($stateParams.arg1);
       }
      else if ($stateParams.arg1  && $stateParams.arg2){
          renewalService.getUser($stateParams.arg1,
    $stateParams.arg2);
      }
       else{
         // other fallback
       }          
    }],
    selectedTab: /* ... */
  }
});
```

Comment: if you look, he OP wants userId also to be optional

Comment: can you write two sample urls for the case when only userId is present and the other when dob and address is present. I don't understand how to represent optional userId or dob in a real world url

Comment: @pranavjindal999 please check demo I posted

Comment: your solution doesn't fulfill the requirement. OP has two apis to get user object-> 
1. by id
2. by dob and address

how would you make an url when dev just has dob and address?

Comment: @pranavjindal999 yea, this is what im writing

Comment: That could work that the solution seems hacky. Such cases should be handled using query string.
```'/user-view?userId&dataeofbirth&address'```

Comment: @pranavjindal999 please post demo,

Comment: modified your demo. http://plnkr.co/edit/ZAIWpuFHxclY9hfpfhQC?p=preview

Comment: Thnak you both for the awesome explanation! I appreciate your effort